# Mongoose Type has no properties in common with type 'DeepPartial<Document>'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some trouble to do an easy thing with mongoose but I get stuck I don't know why.

I have this error `Type '{ time: any; value: any; applianceId: any; }' has no properties in common with type 'DeepPartial<Document>'.`

Here you can find my schema :

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
const applianceDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    applianceId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    time: {type: Number, required: true},
    value: {type: Number, required: true},
});

const ApplianceDataModel = mongoose.model('relationalApplianceData', applianceDataSchema);

export { ApplianceDataModel }
```

my insert code :

```
const appliance = model.appliances.find(a => a.name == data.appliance); // I find the correct appliance here
const doc = {
            time: data.time,
            value: data.value,
            applianceId: appliance._id // I use the objectId here
        };
const applianceDataModel = new ApplianceDataModel(doc); // Error here
```

I don't know what is wrong, I would like to use the objectId object to reference my appliance from my data.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this error applianceId is required and appliance._id will be undefined because you have to wait for model.appliances.find( ..... )

```
// add async to the callback function for your endpoint
app.post('/your_url', async (req,res)=>{

   const appliance = await model.appliances.find(a => a.name == data.appliance);
   if(!appliance) res.status(400).send({error:'appliance not found'});

   console.log(appliance._id); // should console the _id
   const doc = {
        time: data.time,
        value: data.value,
        applianceId: appliance._id 
    };

   const applianceDataModel = new ApplianceDataModel(doc);
   await applianceDataModel.save();
   res.send({message:'Appliance has been saved'}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This error is not a runtime error but a typescript error compilation, so the error appear before I execute the code (not related to an undefined value). Also, model var is already set and appliance is defined, I can ensure you that. I have put a console.log into my loop and the result is correct : https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2019/08/18/19081808260148505.png.

Comment: do you have another schema model? because in the pic you sent the are {_id: any: name:any }